# IntelliJ file synchronize takes forever on SSHFS

Tags: intellij-idea, sshfs

I do all my development on a Mac, and my files are on a remote Linux server. I use SSHFS to access the files. When I am using IntelliJ on a local project, I don't even notice the file synchronization, most likely because it can access the files very quickly. But when I have a project open through SSHFS, the synchronizing takes a very long time, which is a pain because inspections are dependent on synchronization being finished. I can't see any code analysis until the synchronization is done.

I saw one solution where someone moved the intellij project files to a local directory and had the project point to the SSHFS files, but I'd rather have everything in one place.

I need to know how to either speed up the synchronization or make inspections run even if the files are synchronizing.

Answer (score -3):

You should consider having a local copy of all your files on your mac, and using a sync utility like [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) or [RSync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) to keep your files in sync